# Is there any way to compile and statically link ruby libs for Docker?

Tags: ruby, linux, docker

**UPDATED 6 29 2015:**

[InfraRuby compiler and runtime for statically typed Ruby on the JVM!](http://infraruby.com/blog/infraruby-3-7-released)

---

I'd like to have a single binary, statically linked, out of a simple ruby crawler to build a slim docker container.

Something like what Go produces with:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .
```

(from [Building Minimal Docker Containers for Go Applications](https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/)).

Is there a way of doing this with ruby/rails?

Comment: you can compile down to byte code using mruby but that probably won't work for a rails app.  If it's a ruby script though, something to explore.